# Can ML240 polyimide magnet wire handle 50kV when used in inductors?

Tags: high-voltage, insulation, voltage-multiplier, insulation-voltage

I have built ~2mH inductors wired on air core plastic bobbins from AWG26 ML240 polyimide magnet wire and tested them at ~25kV.  They seem to work fine without shorting through the polyimide insulation.

I am designing a Marx generator and would like to use voltages ~50kV per stage instead of 25kV but I do not have a power supply to test the inductors at this voltage level.

Before I fork out the money to buy/build a 50kV DC power source to test the inductors I was hoping someone would know if the magnet wire in those inductors should work ok at 50kV or if it's a lost cause.

AFAIK polyimide magnet wire insulation has the highest dielectric strength of any magnet wire insulation.

Edit:

I don't know the wire length of number of turns. The wire I used is: https://www.remingtonindustries.com/magnet-wire/magnet-wire-240-c-26-awg-polyimide-6-spool-sizes-available/

The bobbin I used 18mm ID, 30mm OD, and 18mm height: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ferroxcube/CP-P36-22-1S/7034192

Comment: What dimensions?

Comment: Length of wire?  Turns?

Comment: When looking at HV insulation in an application like this, remember that although you may have 25kV (or 50kV) end-to-end, you have a significantly lower voltage turn-to-turn. So, as colintd writes below, layering is key (and insulation between layers) to ensure that your polyimide never needs to handle the full voltage in a single layer of insulation.

Comment: Please provide a link to the wire you used.

Comment: At these voltages, you will have partial discharge way before you break down the isolation of your wire. Please show how you intend to build up your inductor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With any HV transformer/inductor the layering is key, as it impacts the turn to turn stress on the wire, in particular the lead outs.  Get this wrong, and no magnet wire will survive.

If the layering is right, the other major problem, especially if you're going up to 50 kV will be corona. If the windings are in free air, they will generate significant ozone which with time will badly attack the insulation.

Short term, you might be fine, but for reliable long term use I would suggest you either need to vacuum impregnate / encapsulate with epoxy, or for a more forgiving setup, oil immerse.

I have made a 100 kV centre tapped transformer wound with standard magnet wire, immersed in oil, and absolutely no issue.

I used a split bobbin approach, so with a centre tapped setup, the centre tap was near the core for both half windings, rather than one having a high voltage to core. The center wire comes out a hole at the side/bottom of the bobbin, not up the inside of the bobbin (as that would place the centre wire and the last layer close to each other).

Then even wound layers for the HV winding, with kraft paper between layers to ensure no mixing of layers. I just trap the paper under a turn and a half of wire to fix it in place as I wind.

This layering is critical as it controls/shapes the interlayer voltage gradient, with each layer effectively isolating the layers on either side. The alternative of random winding gives a significant chance of wires touching which are many turns apart, with resulting high insulation stress.

(There is choice over whether you are better winding alternate layers left-right and right-left, or have a return wire at the end of each layer to keep lay direction the same. Personally I prefer the evenness of alternating which gives a peak potential difference of twice the per layer potential, but others use an end-to-start "return" wire with a goal of reducing interlayer winding stress to the potential of one layer, at the expense on disturbing the uniformity of each layer. )

And finally the oil. I evacuated the tank for a day, then slowly let in the dry transformer oil from the bottom to ensure no voids.

HV lead outs were through homemade tufnol bushes, with the inside ends directly oil immersed, and with corona rings on the outside to limit stress / tracking.

Comment: Did you do anything special at the end of each layer, or did you just bring the wire through a nick in the paper?

Comment: At the end of each layer I simply placed the edge of the precut paper length under the wire, then used the next turn and a half to wrap/hold the paper down.  This worked well for me as I did the winding on a home built machine. I also obviously reversed the "lay" direction to ensure the next layer went the opposite way to the previous on (l-r vs r-l).

Comment: Thanks for that, the simplest ways are the best. So assuming v for the voltage drop end-to-end of a single layer, the maximum voltage across the paper at any point is 2v.

Comment: Exactly. This is well within the wire insulation in most cases, and definitely with paper and oil.

Comment: In your layers paragraph, you might want to emphasise the difference between to-and-fro, and to-and-to for the winding directions of successive layers, the latter resulting in half the layer to layer voltage stress.

Comment: @Neil_UK true at one level, but I find the "return" wire, going from the end of one winding, back to the start of the next, tends to upset the even winding of the next layer.  I suspect this reduces the benefit of the field strength reduction. But do take your point.

Comment: @Neil_UK I've updated answer to highlight options.

Comment: @colintd I don't think there's any 'discussion' about the benefits of to-fro or to-to winding successive layers. The return wire for to-to winding bulks up the winding, sometimes you can lose it where height is free. Where it's indicated for either layer to layer voltage stress, or lower self capacitance, there's likely to be reasonable thickness of interlayer insulation as well, which usefully restores winding evenness. Generally you use to-fro until forced into to-to.

Comment: @colintd If you have some pictures, of either during assembly and/or the finished centre tapped transformer, they would an interesting addition to your answer.

Comment: Sadly made about 35 years ago for university project and the few film photos I took at lost in time.  If you want a nice video of hand winding with paper on a larger scale, have a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4cw757tLm8 .  They are using a nice trick of wrapping the sheet round the wire, which I wish I'd thought of!

Comment: So you would recommend instead of using this bobbin:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ferroxcube/CP-P36-22-1S/7034192
to use this one instead:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ferroxcube/CP-P36-22-2S/7034193

Do you have to wind both sides of the inductor at the same time? Did you use two spools and connect the wires at the middle bobbin indent? or did you use one wire and unwind a bunch of wire from the main spool onto a secondary spool?

Comment: Also, as far as lining up the windings next to each other the 26AWG wire thinness and my basic coil winder make that tough. The spool holder doesn't keep the wire taut. Will using properly cut up craft paper help with that? I saw the video you linked to, I will use that method for winding the craft paper.

Comment: @RobertFrancisJr Not sure how far you'd get, putting 50kV into a bobbin like that. There are special high voltage bobbins with multiple dividers however.